# Python Can't Schedule in Long Periods

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, schedule

I am new to python and I just don't understand why scheduling in long periods doesn't work on python. I have to take record everyday at 20.01 and 08.01. At first I tried schedule 0.6 to do this job like this:

```
schedule.every().day.at("08:01").do(verigondersabah)
schedule.every().day.at("20:01").do(verigonderaksam)
while True:
 schedule.run_pending()
```

this worked fine in short periods like 3-4 hours. I tried it for days to make it work but when the script works for 24 hours I can't save required values to mysql at 20.01 and 08.01.

I tought maybe schedule 0.6 has a problem in long periods and tried to do it myself like this :

```
def saatcheck():
 while True:
  check=datetime.now().strftime("%H%M%S")
  print(check)
  if(check=="080100"):
   verigondersabah()
  elif(check=="200100"):
   verigonderaksam()
  time.sleep(1)
tt6=threading.Thread(target=saatcheck)
tt6.start()
```

Again it works in short periods but no luck with the long periods. Is there anyway that i can run a scheduling job for 24 hours? What might be the problem?
I am trying to run these on raspberry pi by the way.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what happens after 24 hours? Is the script still running? Are you getting any kind of exception? What's *not* working, exactly?

Comment: Are you running your Python script using `screen`, `supervisor`, or a similar tool?

Comment: this looks like the `schedule` package.  It has some very strange behavior (e.g. buggy) and I would recommend using something like `apscheduler` instead

Comment: The main script is still running after 24 hours.I don't get any exceptions. I tried to run script with crontab on raspberry (when i power raspberry script was running) then I tried screen. Still no luck.

Comment: How do you know that tasks are not being executed?

Comment: I check mysql and records are not there. When I run the same script in short periods i can see the records on mysql.

Comment: What happens when you simply add some `print()`s into `verigonderaksm()` when is entered and immediately before it returns?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the called function with something that prints and returns - and checked that this is being called very 12 hours?

Comment: unfortunately i can't see the old prints. I am running the script with ssh connections. Therefore ssh connection can't run properly for 24 hours. I tried your solution to see the prints but ssh connection could stay for about 3 hours. After it disconnects script will stop running. I use crontab or screen to avoid this but with these methods can't see the the logs. But i can check the scheduling jobs with mysql.

Comment: I think one of the problem is that comparing two datetime objects by using '==' it is not a good choice (especially if you add 'seconds' to the mix). In the past I had this problem with daytime objects and I figured out that instead of using '==' it was better to check if datetime.now() was in between a small range

Comment: @LorenzoPaolin how can i check if datetime.now() is in between a range? I tried to convert datetime to string. How can i check if a string in between a range?

Comment: Without converting it into a string. Datetime objects support comparison

Comment: This would be your if statement  => datetime.time(8, 0,0) < time.now() < datetime.time(8, 2, 0). The syntax for datetime.time is datetime.time(hour, minutes, seconds)

Comment: I know its too late but did you try using simple_scheduler ... ? --> https://pypi.org/project/simple-scheduler/